# How to draw a directed graph with arrows showing vertically from bottom to top

Tags: graphing-functions

If I have a directed graph, how can I draw it with arrows showing in general vertically from bottom to top, like showing a class inheritance pattern in OOP(object oriented programming)?

Answer (score 2):

If the graph is acyclic, you can use [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) to assign a vertical level to every vertex.

Comment: Could you please give a working example? Thank you.

Comment: @QiangLi: There are two algorithms in the Wikipedia article, and tons of hits if you google topological sorting -- I don't think it's an efficient use of my time to work out another example here. If you have trouble following the descriptions, please ask a specific question about what you don't understand.